# Celery conf in python

Tags: python, celery

I have tried many things, and searched many questions, yet my problem remains unsolved.

I am using `docker-compose`, `python` `celery` and `rabbitmq` without any other flask or django framework.

I tried many thing to configure celery workers pool, I found just one function that works, but I cant run it with gui instance and using it in celery images does not work,
`app.control.grow_pool`

I am not starting celery with celery command, but with python file.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=autoscaler

```py
# my_celery_app.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery.concurrency.prefork import TaskPool
from celery.worker.autoscale import Autoscaler
from celery import Celery

from analyzer.database_operator import get_db_all_tweet_list

import time
import os

user = os.getenv('LOGIN', 'admin')
password = os.getenv('PASSWORD', 'mypass')
hostname = os.getenv('HOSTNAME', 'localhost')

broker_url = f'amqp://{user}:{password}@{hostname}:5672/'
app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url, namespace="CELERY")


# app.conf.worker_pool = TaskPool
# app.control.worker_max_tasks_per_child = 10
# app.conf.worker_autoscaler = Autoscaler(None, min_concurrency=3, max_concurrency=10)


@app.task
def show(*args, **kwargs):
    duration = 10
    print(f"Start, args: {args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
    for x in range(duration):
        # print(duration - x)
        time.sleep(0.3)

    # print("Bye celery")


get_db_all_tweet_list = app.task(get_db_all_tweet_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.worker_main()
```

another solution that does not work, but it raiser error

```py
# learning_celery.py

from celery.app.control import Control

controller = Control(app)
controller.autoscale(10, 4)
```

```sh
worker_1        | [2020-05-20 19:32:08,311: ERROR/MainProcess] pidbox command error: ValueError('Autoscale not enabled')
worker_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 104, in dispatch
worker_1        |     reply = handle(method, arguments)
worker_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 126, in handle_cast
worker_1        |     return self.handle(method, arguments)
worker_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 120, in handle
worker_1        |     return self.handlers[method](self.state, **arguments)
worker_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/control.py", line 513, in autoscale
worker_1        |     raise ValueError('Autoscale not enabled')
worker_1        | ValueError: Autoscale not enabled
```

Comment: The quickest way to solve your problem is to read the source of the CLI handler for the `--autoscale` argument to the Celery worker. I will check it if I find time...

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want to run the worker by yourself instead of using the provided CLI tool, using [app.worker_main()](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/base.py#L360) then you need to provide arguments in the `argv` list. Since you are mainly concerned about autoscaling (which is deprecated as far as I know - pity, it is a good feature) than, at minimum, argv should be `["--autoscale", "10,3"]`.

So try to replace the `app.worker_main()` line with `app.worker_main(argv=["--autoscale", "10,3"])` and see if it works... If it does not work, then try with `argv=["--autoscale=10,3"]`.

Comment: I fixed other service in my compose, should I refactor project to start celery with `celery -A app worker` now ?

Comment: also, second option lets me start, but nothing has changed